# Selecting Table Name Runtime

Tags: python, pyqt, pymssql

Is it possible to selecting table name runtime . For example.

```
def get_data(self, table_name):
    try:
        self._cursor.execute("select Name from %s",(table_name))
        row = self._cursor.fetchall()
        return row
    except:
        raise DbException("An error occured...")
```

This code is not working .Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format` to substitute your placeholder with the table name:

```
def get_data(self, table_name):
    try:
        self._cursor.execute("select Name from {}".format(table_name))
        row = self._cursor.fetchall()
        return row
    except:
        raise DbException("An error occured...")
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer